# How to use a viewpager inside another fragment and not get any lifecycle issues?

Tags: android, xml, firebase, kotlin, android-lifecycle

**This is my profile fragment where I am using a viewpager :**

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewPagerAdaptor: ViewPagerAdaptor

    private val binding: FragmentProfileBinding by lazy {
        FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    private lateinit var currentUserId: String

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // User id
        currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

        // Edit profile button
        binding.editProfileButton.setOnClickListener{
             startActivity(
                 Intent(requireActivity(), EditProfileActivity::class.java)
                     .putExtra("userId", currentUserId)
                     .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)
             )
        }

        // add post button
        binding.addPostButton.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), AddPostActivity::class.java))
        }

        // Settings Button
        binding.settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), SettingsActivity::class.java))
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun init() {

        // Setup tabs
        setUpTabs()
    }

    /*
    * set up tab layout : My posts | My Incubates | My Bookmarks
    * */
    private fun setUpTabs() {
        viewPagerAdaptor = ViewPagerAdaptor(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
        viewPagerAdaptor.addFragments(MyPostFragment())
        viewPagerAdaptor.addFragments(MyIncubatesFragment())
        viewPagerAdaptor.addFragments(MyBookmarksFragment())
        binding.profileViewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdaptor
        binding.profileTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(binding.profileViewPager)

        binding.profileTabLayout.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.grid_view)
        binding.profileTabLayout.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.video_play_outlined)
        binding.profileTabLayout.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark)
    }
}
```

There is lifecycle issues with this implementation, viewpager inside a fragment is not working fine with my above implementation.

I expect the profile fragment to come to the previous state, when moving from the another activity to this or onBackPressed.

Please help me solve this. (following is the stack trace)

```
2023-12-11 10:26:46.327  1311-18277 AwareLog                system_server                        W  AwareMem_Reclaim: generateCompressList procsGroups error!
2023-12-11 10:26:46.698  1311-1355  ZrHung.App...rentWindow system_server                        D  handleMessage CHECK_TRANS_WINDOW_ERROR_MSG
2023-12-11 10:26:50.796  1311-18277 AwareLog                system_server                        W  AwareMem_Reclaim: generateCompressList procsGroups error!
2023-12-11 10:26:52.875  1311-1947  ZrHung.App...ocusWindow system_server                        D  FocusWindowErrorScene CheckFreezeScreen
2023-12-11 10:26:53.072  1311-1609  InputDispatcher         system_server                        W  channel '5fd2c33 com.bishal.incubator/com.bishal.incubator.profile.EditProfileActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2023-12-11 10:26:53.074  1311-1609  InputDispatcher         system_server                        W  channel '8a81dad com.bishal.incubator/com.bishal.incubator.home.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2023-12-11 10:26:53.074  1311-1609  InputDispatcher         system_server                        W  channel 'a489a9a com.bishal.incubator/com.bishal.incubator.add_post.AddPostActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2023-12-11 10:26:53.074  1311-1609  InputDispatcher         system_server                        W  channel '1def340 com.bishal.incubator/com.bishal.incubator.home.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (18502) for package com.bishal.incubator ----------------------------
2023-12-11 10:26:53.303 18181-19220 DropBoxUtil             com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  [AppErrors] null InputStream [CONTEXT service_id=254 ]
                                                                                                    java.io.IOException: null InputStream
                                                                                                        at cgon.d(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):209)
                                                                                                        at cgmv.l(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):7)
                                                                                                        at cgmp.apply(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):37)
                                                                                                        at rlc.apply(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):5)
                                                                                                        at rlo.apply(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):45)
                                                                                                        at cyxp.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):3)
                                                                                                        at dhiq.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):13)
                                                                                                        at dnvc.d(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):3)
                                                                                                        at dnve.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):42)
                                                                                                        at dnwp.execute(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.h(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.hi(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):40)
                                                                                                        at dnve.g(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):13)
                                                                                                        at cyxf.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):20)
                                                                                                        at dhio.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):13)
                                                                                                        at dnwv.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):20)
                                                                                                        at dnyy.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):3)
                                                                                                        at dnxz.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):21)
                                                                                                        at dnza.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):5)
                                                                                                        at dnwx.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):53)
                                                                                                        at dnwp.execute(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnwx.execute(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):76)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.h(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.hi(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):40)
                                                                                                        at dnwz.c(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):31)
                                                                                                        at cyxj.i(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):18)
                                                                                                        at cyxo.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):10)
                                                                                                        at dhiq.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):13)
                                                                                                        at dnvc.d(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):3)
                                                                                                        at dnve.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):42)
                                                                                                        at dnwp.execute(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.h(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.hi(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):40)
                                                                                                        at dnve.g(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):13)
                                                                                                        at cyxr.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):20)
                                                                                                        at dhio.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):13)
                                                                                                        at dnwv.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):20)
                                                                                                        at dnyy.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):3)
                                                                                                        at dnxz.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):21)
                                                                                                        at dnza.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):5)
                                                                                                        at dnwx.run(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):53)
                                                                                                        at dnwp.execute(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnwx.execute(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):76)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.h(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):1)
                                                                                                        at dnuy.hi(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):40)
                                                                                                        at dnwz.c(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):31)
                                                                                                        at cyxy.c(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):56)
                                                                                                        at cyxy.b(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):10)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@234523022@23.45.23 (100400-587848529):375)
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (19232) for package com.bishal.incubator ----------------------------
```

Comment: "the app is crashing" - that means that there's a stack trace in your logcat. Please include the full stack trace here.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for pointing out, I have mentioned in the problem now, you can now check it. (I hope this is what you were asking?)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **250** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, what is the exact line of code that produces that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have redefined the code sir, it might be helpful in understanding the problem. As I am not sure what part of my code's line is generating the error, So I have included all of it (sorry folks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use (under the `setUpTabs()`):

```
viewPagerAdaptor = ViewPagerAdaptor(childFragmentManager)
```

Instead of :

```
viewPagerAdaptor = ViewPagerAdaptor(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
```

Below is the ViewPagerAdaptor class :

```
class ViewPagerAdaptor (fragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    private val fragmentList = mutableListOf<Fragment>()
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }

    fun addFragments(fragment: Fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
    }

}
```